# NLog для windows-сервиса

Tags: c#, windows-service, .net-5, nlog

Создаю windows-сервис (.NET 5) и хочу использовать NLog. Все работает, но почему-то в лог еще пишутся такие записи:

> 2021-10-20 18:22:44.8017|INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Application
> started. Hosting environment: Production; Content root path:
> C:\Users<...>\source\repos<path>\bin\Release\net5.0\publish\
>
> 2021-10-20 18:27:35.8279|INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Application
> is shutting down...

Может быть используется как встроенный логгер Microsoft, так и NLog? Как можно использовать только один?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logBuilder) =>
            {
                logBuilder.AddNLog(new NLogLoggingConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("NLog")));
            });            
}
```

Конфигурация NLog в **appsettings.json**:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "NLog": {
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "targets": {
      "async": true,
      "logfileMain": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "${basedir}/logs/nlog-${shortdate}.log"
      },
      "logfileError": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "${basedir}/logs/nlog-error-${shortdate}.log"
      },
      "logconsole": {
        "type": "Console"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "maxlevel": "Warn",
        "writeTo": "logfileMain"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minlevel": "Error",
        "writeTo": "logfileError"
      },
      {
        "logger": "Microsoft.*",
        "maxlevel": "Info",
        "final": true
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Trace",
        "writeTo": "logconsole"
      }      
    ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Добавил в сервис дополнительную библиотеку и в лог теперь пишется еще информация от нее (см. далее). Как можно настроить NLog, чтобы выводилось в лог только то, что выводится через _logger.Info("Текст"), _logger.Debug("Текст") и т.д.

> 2021-10-21
> 12:39:53.9300|INFO|Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl|Initialized
> Scheduler Signaller of type: Quartz.Core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
> 2021-10-21 12:39:53.9300|INFO|Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler|Quartz
> Scheduler created 2021-10-21
> 12:39:53.9300|INFO|Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler|JobFactory set to:
> Quartz.Simpl.MicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory 2021-10-21
> 12:39:53.9300|INFO|Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore|RAMJobStore initialized.
> 2021-10-21 12:39:53.9300|INFO|Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler|Scheduler
> meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v3.3.3.0) 'QuartzScheduler' with
> instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'   Scheduler class:
> 'Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.   NOT STARTED.
> Currently in standby mode.   Number of jobs executed: 0   Using thread
> pool 'Quartz.Simpl.DefaultThreadPool' - with 10 threads.   Using
> job-store 'Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support
> persistence. and is not clustered.
>
> 2021-10-21 12:39:53.9300|INFO|Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory|Quartz
> scheduler 'QuartzScheduler' initialized 2021-10-21
> 12:39:53.9300|INFO|Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory|Quartz scheduler
> version: 3.3.3.0 2021-10-21
> 12:39:53.9648|INFO|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Adding 1
> jobs, 1 triggers. 2021-10-21
> 12:39:53.9648|INFO|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Adding job:
> DEFAULT.HelloWorldJob 2021-10-21
> 12:39:53.9648|DEBUG|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Scheduling
> job: DEFAULT.HelloWorldJob with trigger: DEFAULT.HelloWorldJob-trigger
> 2021-10-21
> 12:39:53.9943|DEBUG|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Rescheduling
> job: DEFAULT.HelloWorldJob with updated trigger:
> DEFAULT.HelloWorldJob-trigger 2021-10-21
> 12:39:54.0082|INFO|Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler|Scheduler
> QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.

Comment: В методе [CreateDefaultBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) конфигурируется логирование по умолчанию (см. секции Remarks). Настройки берутся из узла `"Logging"` файла "appsettings.json". Можно либо этот узел отредактировать (удалить), либо удалить ставший ненужным дефолтный провайдер: `logBuilder.ClearProviders();`

Comment: Не сработало (убрал секцию, добавил ClearProviders).

Answer (score 0):

Укажите для `"logger": "Microsoft.*"` куда логи писать (writeTo). Скорее всего оно их пишет без указания в первый объявленный таргет. Возможно, вам нужен [null](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Null-target) таргет.

Comment: Добавил уточнение в вопрос (update)